# jQueryMobile Can't scroll down to dynamically created page content

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

Using jQueryMobile and the iscrollview plugin, I am having trouble scrolling down on a page that contains dynamically added content.
This is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" class="care-plan-fields"  id="scroll-wrapper" data-iscroll>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="field1">
                    <label for="field1Text" id="field1Label"></label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="field1Text" spellcheck="true" autocorrect="on" autocapitalize="on"></textarea>
                </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field2Text" id="field2Label"></label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="field2Text" spellcheck="true" autocorrect="on" autocapitalize="on"></textarea>
                </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field3Text" id="field3Label"></label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="field3Text" spellcheck="true" autocorrect="on" autocapitalize="on"></textarea>
                </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="field4">
                    <label for="field4Text" id="field4Label"></label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="2" id="field4Text" spellcheck="true" autocorrect="on" autocapitalize="on"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
```

I add data to textareas in the **pagebeforeshow** handler like this:

```
$("label[for='field1Text']").text(carePlan.fields[0].label);
$('#field1Text').val(carePlan.fields[0].text);
```

And then immediately call refresh on the scroll view to get it to resize:

```
$('#scroll-wrapper').iscrollview("refresh");
```

However, while the textareas have resized to accommodate the size of the text added to them, the page does not seem to resize and I can't scroll down if that added data extends past the bottom of the page.

If I navigate away from the page and back again, I can scroll down fully.

I think it is some rendering problem and can't figure out how to re-render the page without navigating away an back again. (note the iscrollview plugin is working for other list views within my app, but they don't have dynamically added data like this.)
Anyone have any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are those other list views also the main content div for the page?

Likely iscroll is conflicting with the jquery mobile layout settings - the content div is resized to fit the content by jquery mobile, then iscroll takes that as the available on screen area, even though it is not actually all visible. The out of box scrolling that comes with the content div doesn't take effect either because iscroll is catching all the touch events.

Comment: This is a working listview: '<div data-role="content" data-iscroll="">
                    
                    <ul data-role="listview" id="qt-listview-patients"  data-inset="true"  data-filter="true">
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>'

Comment: That has a single child element (ul), while the one that isn't working has multiple child divs. Try wrapping those with another inner div.